# How to make a all the three tables to display at same height

Tags: html, css

I have three tables table1,table2,table3 all wrapped inside a table, while adding different size of contents to the tables each expands to different height , how to make all the three tables display at same height even after adding different size of content

HTML :

```
<div class="csdiv">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <table class="cstable" width="100%" height="265">
                    <tr height="35">
                        <th width="33%" nowrap>Table1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="FFFFFF" width="275">


                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="cstable" width="100%" height="265">
                    <tr height="35">
                        <th nowrap width="34%" nowrap>Table2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="FFFFFF" width="275">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="cstable" width="100%" height="265">
                    <tr height="35">
                        <th nowrap width="33%" nowrap>Table3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="FFFFFF" width="275">


                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>                                  
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.csdiv {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.cstable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.cstable th {
    background-color: #A3C2FF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

JSFIDDLE : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8hm3/2/)

Comment: *sidenote:* use CSS instead of `bgcolor` attribute. Also, use `<br>` or `<p>` to break lines. Also, your CSS is clumsy; consider using CSS shorthands.

Comment: will the bgcolor affect the table height

Comment: not related. Side notes are just comments of your codes.  `height`, `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` should be avoided too.

Comment: If I may give you an advice, try not to post the absolutely same code you are using, as this is hard to read. There is not point in scrolling hundreds of HTML code just to skip repeating lines of _repeating_ characters. Use comments or some other way to point that the actual content is long. You already have a jsFiddle too.

Comment: some times guys never understand the problem so i just shown everything , sorry

Comment: @Aravind30790, It is assumed people who can answer your questions are professionals. They would handle your problem with the jsFiddle alone, so (too much) verbosity will likely hurt your reputation (by causing downvotes). I personally do not down-vote such cases, and besides the long code the question is actually a good fit for SO, but some people do not have the patience to scroll all this trough, and it is reasonable. If something is unclear, you'd better listen to comments of the other users and improve accordingly. Comments for removing redundant content are very less-likely here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parent elements has no `height` set, so the `table` is taking height only equal to the content.To make it full height, add

```
 html,body{
    height:100%; /*give full height to document */
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
 table{
    height:100%; /* stretch table to parents height*/
 }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8hm3/3/)

Comment: @Mr.Alien : My day is made....aliens edited my answer....this is gonna be one hell of a weekend!! :D

Comment: +1 - Moral of the story (for myself): Never type out an answer, before refreshing the page! :-(

Comment: @techfoobar else type so fast that you bleed

Comment: @techfoobar : i seldom beat alien...happened first time for me!!

Comment: @Mr.Alien : haha...easier said than done...i better close my account than bleed!! :p

Comment: @NoobEditor you would never close that

Comment: @Mr.Alien : if bleeding is the only thing balancing the scale...sure i would!! :p